# Updating data on a XML DOM c++ using tinyxml-2

Tags: c++, dom, tinyxml2

I was wondering how could I update the data on the DOM for a certain attribute? I've searched but I couldn't find anything. Basically, I have an attribute called Hour(for example it's "11:03") and I want the text from that specific attribute to be changed to something like "11:04" or any other different text.

```
if( strcmp(Code1,Code2) == 0 )
{
    strcpy(New,NewHour);
    Element->FindAttribute("Hour")->SetAttribute(New); // here I want it to be changed in the DOM but I dont know how to do it
}
```

Later edit: This is what I've tried, but it's telling me FindAttribute() is private..

Comment: What does the documentation say?  And have you tried your sample?

Comment: Yes, it does not work. I've searched the documentation but I could not find it

Comment: What is the exact type of `Element`?

Comment: It's an XMLelement

Comment: No need to FindAttribute.  SetAttribute takes the attribute name and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that you can use `SetAttribute` which accepts the attribute **name** and **value** as parameters.

However, **TinyXml2** does have a methodology for using `FindAttribute` because I have this code in my application:

```
// We need to get the assistant
const XMLAttribute *pAttrAssistant = const_cast<const XMLElement*>(pStudent)->FindAttribute("Assistant");
if (pAttrAssistant != nullptr)
{
    LPCTSTR szAssistant = CA2CT(pAttrAssistant->Value(), CP_UTF8);
    SetStudentInfo(eSchool, eAssign, strStudent, szAssistant, iStudyPoint);
}
else
{
    // TODO: Throw exception if Assistant attribute missing
}
```

As you can see, I use the `FindAttribute` method and I have no compilation errors. If you look closely you will see that I am using `const` and that is the key.

The class exposes two methods:

[image: FindAttribute]

One of them is set to `private` as you have already found out. But the `const` overload is set as `public`:

[image: Access]